# Batch File to conditionally replace entire lines of a file

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have a txt file with various lines or text. It is a config file, so each line is a new config setting.

What I need is to create a batch file which will search this txt file for a line that STARTS WITH a certain string, and then replace the entire line with something else. I also need to preserve empty lines.

For example, given the following text file

```
Line 1
Line 2

Line 3 with some unknown text afterwards

Line 4 with some unknown text afterwards
```

I would want to replace the entire Line 3 with "This is replacement line 3" and the entire line 4 with a "This is replacement line 4"

```
Line 1
Line 2

This is replacement line 3

This is replacement line 4
```

I can do the above if I know what the entire Line 3 and Line 4 strings will be by using the code below, but not if I only know the start of the line. This also does not preserve empty lines

```
:Variables
set InputFile=myfile.txt
set OutputFile=myfile.txt
set "_strFind1=Line 3 with some unknow text afterwards"
set "_strFind2=Line 4 with some unknow text afterwards"
set "_strInsert1=This is replacement line 3
set "_strInsert2=This is replacement line 4

:Replace
>"%OutputFile%" (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
       if "%%A" equ "%_strFind1%" (echo %_strInsert1%)
       else if "%%A" equ "%_strFind2%" (echo %_strInsert2%)
       else (echo %%A)
    )
)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
type "file.txt" |repl "^startingtext.*" "New line of text" >"newfile.txt"
```

Note that the replacement text is microsoft replacement expression and may need some `escaping` if the text isn't shown properly.